# Navigation bar not dismissed on unwinding segue when UISearchDisplay is shown

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller, unwind-segue

I have a secondary screen in an app reached by a custom segue. I programmatically unwind the segue by calling:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

that for some reason worked fine, notwithstanding the segue was a custom one.
Yet when I dismiss the Controller while a recently introduced UISearchDisplayController table is displayed, the navigation bar is left even on the main viewController even if I hide it in the viewWillAppear:animated: callback.
[image]
If I dismiss it when the normal table is displayed, no unexpected navigation bar appears instead.

So I tried to implement the correct way of unwinding the segue by executing:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToMainMenu" sender:self];
```

but the program crashes complaining it may not find the segue:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'unwindToMainMenu''

albeit of course the winding identifier is well present in the storyboard as you may see at:
[image]

In any case the top bar is also present on the main controller in this latter implementation when normally dismissing the controller while the UISearchDisplayController table is shown, so the issue seems not to be connected to the unwinding segue.

The Apple tutorial program unfortunately does not present manual unwinding segues and other tutorials present the thing the way I have tried to implement it. I did not find any information about parasitic navigation bars connected to searchDisplay tables either.
How may I fix my problem?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the spurious navigation bar by calling:

```
self.searchDisplayController.active=NO;
```

Yet I am still puzzled on why the segue crashes.